# with push bottom If value cell = Combobox - Show in userform combobox - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I want to complete the code as follows:
Pressing the "CommandButton1", if the cell is equal to the value of the "ComboBox1", is selected and displayed in the "ComboBox1".

My code (not complete):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("A1:B5")
Me.ComboBox1.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "" Then
    Beep
    Else
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = xRg Then
    'What code should I write here to if
    '"Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")=Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("A1:B5")" show the amount in comboBox1?
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So... what's preventing you from doing what you want? That's what your question should be about.

Comment: Either there is a missing `End Sub` in your first event procedure `Sub UserForm_Click()` or you have to delete the first code line completely if you want to declare the `xRg` object variable in the declaration head on top of UserForm for all procedures therein. In any case it is not possible to use a `Sub` within another `Sub` or `Function`

Comment: I simplified the code. I hope you understand what I meant by the description inside the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to match a value in a comboboxes hidden 2nd column and highlight a found item**

It wasn't *that* easy to understand what you actually wanted to do.

As you are referring to a two columns data range `A:B` but display only the first range column (possibly identifying e.g. *names or IDs*) in a combobox, I assume the following:

> - After clicking the `CommandButton1` control and
> - under the condition that a given **cell value** (`A1`) equals the 2nd **value** column of `ComboBox1` (*possibly hidden*),
> - the corresponding `ComboBox1` item (*displaying e.g. names*) should be selected (highlighted).

**Applied method**

The essential code line within the `CommandButton1_Click` event procedure is the assignment of a possible **match** position to the variable `pos`:

`pos = Application.Match(myVal, Application.Index(Me.ComboBox1.List, 0, 2), 0)`

As ►**`Application.Match`** needs a **one dimensional** array and `ComboBox1.List` is *2-dimensional*, the `Application.Index` function has to extract the *2nd* (hidden) combobox column (containing values) from the combo list thus getting a 1-dim array now as argument.

...`Application.Index(Me.ComboBox1.List, 0, 2)`        ' c.f. Note *)

- *) Note* that the row index in the `Application.Index` function above has to be set to `0`, so that the column index ►`2` can isolate the 2nd column only.

If a **match** position has been found, the variable `pos` receives the numeric item number which can be used to select a found item by resetting the Comboboxes `.ListIndex` (subtracting 1 as the box indices are zero based).

If **no corresponding value** has been found in the combobox, `pos` gets an error returned and it's therefore necessary to avoid an error message by checking this variable via the ►`IsError()` function (this is why `pos` has to be declared as **Variant** and not only as *Long* to avoid type mismatches errors.)

**UserForm code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim xrg   As Range
Set xrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LookupLists").Range("A1:B5")
With Me.ComboBox1
    .List = xrg.Value2
    .ColumnCount = 2            ' << provide for data of both columns
    .ColumnWidths = .Width      ' << show only first column in full box width
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim pos As Variant                      ' item position has to be variant to allow IsError()
Dim myVal
myVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
If myVal = "" Then
   Beep
Else                                    ' try to get a match and its position
   pos = Application.Match(myVal, Application.Index(Me.ComboBox1.List, 0, 2), 0)
   If IsError(pos) Then pos = 0          ' avoid error msg if not found :-)
   Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = pos - 1      ' goto item no: index is zero based!
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Dear T.M.! Thank you for your work. Your code seems to be correct, but does not select and display the equal amount in the "combobox1".

Comment: You can easily set the `.ColumnWidths` property in the `UserForm_Initialize()` procedure to some point values, e.g. `= "50;50"` (instead of displaying the first id column only over the full combo width) to Show the hidden values column as well. - @FirstLast

Comment: I noticed the hide of the value. You put the equal amount in the second column of the combobox1. While I meant the first column. However, code works. Thank you for your work.